# write out the whole list of inputs in a class for model prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code, a very simple model applying sklearn in python based on BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin. It aims to report the prediction score (y) of a city(X). Here, as a simple model, I only hope it to report the mean score of a city as its prediction value whenever the city is called.

```
class MeanClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __inif__(self):
        self.cityid_ = []
        self.cntX = []

    def X3(self, X):
        self.cityid_, idx = np.unique(X, return_inverse = True)
        self.cntX = map(list(self.cityid_).index, X)
        return self.cntX

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.meanclasses_, meanindicies = np.unique(y, return_inverse = True)
        self.cityid_, idx = np.unique(X, return_inverse = True)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({"X":X, "y":y})
        self.mean_ = self.df.groupby(['X'].mean())

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.df['y']['X']
```

To use the class, I have B, in which city is a list of cities that serve as X and stars as y in the class.

```
B = MeanClassifier()
asncityid = city

B.fit(asncityid, stars)
pred = B.predict(asncityid[2]) #use the third city in the city list for prediction
print(pred)
```

As I run this code, I receive the following error

```
  `File "ml2_cp.py", line 66, in <module>
   pred = B.predict(asncityid[2])
  File "ml2_cp.py", line 58, in predict
  return self.df['y']['X'] ## using sklearn requires all X inputs
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 583, in __getitem__
  result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1980, in get_value
  tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3332)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3035)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4084)
KeyError: 'X'`
```

I am pretty confused, however, how to leave the whole list of X in `def predict(self, X)` I am sure my way of writing it is not right as I also have `y` in there. Please let me know any possible solution and I would like to further explain my code and question if they are not clear. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, you have "received the error below" but list the line number and not the error.  Was there an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you want to have

```
self.mean_ = self.df.groupby(['X']).mean()
```

instead of

```
self.mean_ = self.df.groupby(['X'].mean())
```

and

```
return self.mean_.ix[X].values
```

instead of

```
return self.df['y']['X']
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I even didn't know .ix  I need to look it up!!